# If a class has @XmlElement property, it cannot have @XmlValue property

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I get the following error:

```
If a class has @XmlElement property, it cannot have @XmlValue property
```

**updated** class:

```
    @XmlType(propOrder={"currencyCode", "amount"})
    @XmlRootElement(name="priceInclVat")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class PriceInclVatInfo {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String currency;
    @XmlValue
    private String currencyCode;
    private double amount;

    public PriceInclVatInfo() {}

    public PriceInclVatInfo(String currency, String currencyCode, double amount) {
        this.currency = currency;
        this.currencyCode = currencyCode;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    public String getCurrencyCode() {
        return currencyCode;
    }

    public void setCurrencyCode(String currencyCode) {
        this.currencyCode = currencyCode;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

}
```

I want to achive the following output, with an element attribute and value:

```
<currencyCode plaintext="£">GBP</currencyCode>
```

How can I achieve this? Is it possible if I have @XmlRootElement(name="priceInclVat")?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For the error:

> If a class has @XmlElement property, it cannot have @XmlValue property

Since you have specified field access, by default the unannotated `amount` field is treated as having `@XmlElement`.

```
private double amount;
```

You can do one of the following:

1. Annotate `amount` with `@XmlAttribute`
2. Annotate `amount` with `@XmlTransient`.
3. Change`@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` to `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` so that only annotated fields are treated as mapped.

---

> How can I achieve this? Is it possible if I have
>   @XmlRootElement(name="priceInclVat")?

You can wrap the instance of `PriceInclVatInfo` in an instance of `JAXBElement` to override the root element and marshal that.

Comment: Thanks, I annotated amount with @XmlAttribute and that solved my problem.