# Map Java Object to @XmlElement Value

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, annotations

The LocationType Set coming null when I'm running JAXBxmlToJava. Can any body suggest how to map type component of xml to LocationType Object of Java.
I have following arc-response.xml:-

```
<address_component>
   <long_name>BMC Colony</long_name>
   <short_name>BMC Colony</short_name>
   <type>neighborhood</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
```

And Following Code, AddressComponent:-

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "address_component")
public class AddressComponent {

    @XmlElement(name = "long_name")
    private String longName;
    @XmlElement(name = "short_name")
    private String shortName;
    @XmlElement(name = "type")
    private Set<LocationType> locationTypeSet;
    //Setter Getter
}
```

LocationType:-

```
@XmlRootElement(name="type")
public class LocationType {

    private Integer locationTypeId;
    @XmlElement(name = "type")
    private String type;
    private String status;
    //Setter Getter
}
```

JAXBxmlToJava.java:-

```
    public class JAXBxmlToJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("arc-response.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(AddressComponent.class);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            AddressComponent geoResponse = (AddressComponent) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
            System.out.println(geoResponse);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need [`@XmlValue`](https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.1/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlValue.html) to map a text node (e.g. 'neighborhood') to a field in a custom class.

When I tested your code, the `Set<LocationType>` wasn't `null` - there were two `LocationType`s in it, but *their* `type` field *was* `null`. I'm not sure if that is what you meant in your question.

When I changed the `LocationType` class to

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "type")
public class LocationType {

    private Integer locationTypeId;
    @XmlValue
    private String type;
    private String status;
    // Setter Getter
}
```

it worked.

Comment: Yes you got me right "their type field was null". I used @-XmlValue but I'm getting following exception.
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
If a class has @-XmlElement property, it cannot have @-XmlValue property.
 this problem is related to the following location:
  at private java.lang.String com.test.core.LocationType.type
  at com.test.core.LocationType
  at public java.util.Set com.leaks.impl.model.geo.location.AddressComponent.getLocationTypeSet()
  at com.leaks.impl.model.geo.location.AddressComponent

Comment: ignore "-" as stackoverflow not allowing me to write @ with some String.

Comment: Do you have separate class files for `AddressComponent` and `LocationType`? And did you remove the other `@XmlElement`s from the `LocationType`?

Comment: The solution worked very well. Thank you very much Glorfindel..:)

Comment: - create setter getters then we will face the problem as mentioned in first comment .

Comment: You could try the suggestions in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25998789/4751173).